# Removing Blog Homepage Title Refinery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs, title, refinerycms

Following the tutorial advice, I've successfully removed the body_content_title from other pages. However, on the blog home page I can't seem to get the title to disappear. I've tried setting the :body_content_title to null as per the FAQ, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<% content_for :body_content_title => ""%>
```

Looking at the index.html.erb view, it seems that the title information is contained in the line

```
<% content_for :body_content_left do %>
```

but I can't seem to find where the information for :body_content_left is entered/rendered. Any help to clear this up would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for reading this, 
DC

Answer (score 8):

I've been stucked in this for some hours now, and I figured it out how to solve it.

I'm using refinery-blog Version 2.0.4

and what I did was override the index file:

```
rake refinery:override view=refinery/blog/posts/index
```

then replaced line 19(`<%= render :partial => "/refinery/content_page" %>`) with:

```
<%= render :partial => "/refinery/content_page", :locals => { :remove_automatic_sections => true }  %>
```

You can also replace the same line with:

```
<%= render '/refinery/content_page', :hide_sections => :body_content_title %>
```

two ways to write the same thing, but I guess the second one is cleaner.

Comment: exactly what I was hoping to find.  awesome!